# Hay day neighborhood not appearing in search list

Tags: hay-day

We created a neighborhood and we need to recruit more members to it. The problem is that our neighborhood isn't listed when we try to search for it by typing in its name. We tried this from other devices and other people's farms also. So how can others find us then? What could be the problem?